# Connecting to MySQL server on another PC in LAN

Tags: mysql, lan

I have MySQL setup in a PC on my *local network*, how do I connect to it?

I also have MySQL installed on this computer (which I want to use to connect to the database).

I tried the following but it's not working:

```
mysql -u user -h 192.168.1.28:3306 -p password
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '192.168.1.28:3306' (0)
```

---

### EDIT

Thanks for your help. Anyway, I connect without 3306 and I have another problem. MACBOOK is the name of my client computer.

```
mysql -u user -ppassword -h 192.168.1.28 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'MACBOOK' (using password: YES)
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a new question (and authentication problems are something different than connection problems), please research again and if you don't find an answer (which I heavily doubt), ask a new question. Also, please read one of the many beginners introductions into MySQL – which should answer your question right away.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql
Because you need to open your MySQL server to the outside by editing the CNF file, as described in this answer.

Answer (score 25):

That was a very useful question! Since we need to run the application with a centralized database, we should give the privileges to that computer in LAN  to access the particular database hosted in LAN PC. Here is the solution for that!

1. Go to MySQL server
2. Type the following code to grant access for other pc:

   ```sql
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root_password';
   ```
3. then type:

   ```sql
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```

Replace  `%` with the IP you want to grant access for!

Comment: Its rather dangerous allowing `root` the SuperUser to be used from any ip in the universe. It would be better to create a new user account with access to only the database in question, and with only the minimum privilages to do what is required by the remote access.

Comment: This answer is really helpful! And yes as @RiggsFolly said create a new account first then do it .

Comment: I agree it's dangerous, BUT is it crazy to do this on a dev machine in a small home office?

Comment: @user3811169 how to remove the privilege after ward

Comment: `ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table`

Answer (score 20):

#### Users who can Install `MySQL Workbench` on `MySQL Server` Machine

If you use or have MySQL Workbench on the MySQL Server PC you can do this with just a few clicks. *Recommend only for development environment*.

1. Connect to MySQL Server

[image: Connect to MySQL Server with MySQL Workbench]

2. Find this option `Users and Privileges` from `Navigator` and click on it.

[image: Users and Privileges - MySQL Workbench]

3. Select `root` user and change value for `Limit to Hosts Matching` to `%`.

[image: Users and Privileges - MySQL Workbench]

4. The click `Apply` at the bottom.

This should enable root user to access MySQL Server from remote machine.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have MySQL on your local computer, you do not need to bother with the IP address of the machine. Just use localhost:

```
mysql -u user -p
```

or

```
mysql -hlocalhost -u user -p
```

If you cannot login with this, you must find out what usernames (user@host) exist in the MySQL Server locally. Here is what you do:

- **Step 01) Startup MySQL so that no passwords are require no passwords and denies TCP/IP connections**

  ```
  service mysql restart --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
  ```

  Keep in mind that standard SQL for adding users, granting and
  revoking privileges are disabled.
- **Step 02) Show users and hosts**

  ```
  select concat(''',user,'''@''',host,'''') userhost,password from mysql.user;
  ```
- **Step 03) Check your password to make sure it works**

  ```
  select user,host from mysql.user where password=password('YourMySQLPassword');
  ```

  If your password produces no output for this query, you have a bad
  password.

  If your password produces output for this query, look at the users
  and hosts. If your host value is '%', your should be able to connect
  from anywhere. If your host is 'localhost', you should be able to
  connect locally.

  Make user you have '`root'@'localhost`' defined.

  Once you have done what is needed, just restart mysql normally

  ```
  service mysql restart
  ```

  If you are able to connect successfully on the macbook, run this
  query:

  ```
  SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
  ```

  [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL

  [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in
  MySQL

Let us know what happens !!!

UPDATE 2012-02-13 20:47 EDT

Login to the remote server and repeat Step 1-3

See if any user allows remote access (i.e, host in mysql.user is '%'). If you do not, then add 'user'@'%' to mysql.user.

Comment: I do have mysql in my localhost, but I want to connect to mysql on the other PC.

Answer (score 4):

Follow a simple checklist:

1. Try pinging the machine `ping 192.168.1.2`
2. Ensure MySQL is running on the specified port `3306` i.e. it has not been modified.
3. Ensure that the other PC is not blocking inbound connections on that port. If it is, add a firewall exception to allow connections on port `3306` and allow inbound connections in general.
4. It would be nice if you could post the exact error as it is displayed when you attempt to make that connection.

Answer (score 4):

In ***Ubuntu*** Follow these steps:

1. Set bind-address at  `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d`

   Change `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to `bind-address = 192.24.805.50 # your IP`
2. Grant permission for the remote machine

   ```
   mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'[remoteip]' IDENTIFIED
   BY 'anypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   ```
3. Then try connect from remote machine

   `mysql -u root -h 192.24.805.50 -p`

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql -u user -h 192.168.1.2 -p
```

This should be enough for connection to MySQL server.
Please, check the firewall of `192.168.1.2` if remote connection to MySQL server is enabled.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to any mysql database should be like this:

`$mysql -h hostname -Pportnumber -u username -p` (then enter)

Then it will ask for password. Note: Port number should be closer to -P or it will show error. Make sure you know what is your mysql port. Default is 3306 and is optional to specify the port in this case. If its anything else you need to mention port number with -P or else it will show error.

For example:
`$mysql -h 10.20.40.5 -P3306 -u root -p` (then enter)

```
Password:My_Db_Password
```

Gubrish about product you using.

```
mysql>_
```

Note: If you are trying to connect a db at different location make sure  you can ping to that server/computer.

```
$ping 10.20.40.5
```

It should return TTL with time you got back PONG.
If it says destination unreachable then you cannot connect to remote mysql no matter what.

In such case contact your Network Administrator or Check your cable connection to your computer till the end of your target computer. Or check if you got LAN/WAN/MAN or internet/intranet/extranet working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify ':3306' after the IP, it's the default port for MySQL.

And if your MySQL server runs with another port than 3306, then you have to add '-P [port]' instead of adding it to the IP address.

The MySQL client won't recognize the syntax "host:port", you HAVE to use -P [port] instead.

And btw, if you use '-p password', it won't work and will ask you the password again. You have to stick the password to the -p : -ppassword. (still, it's a very bad habit, because anyone that could do a PS on your server could see the plain password...)

Answer (score 0):

actually you shouldn't specify port in the host name. Mysql has special option for port (if port differs from default)

kind of

```
mysql --host=192.168.1.2 --port=3306
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
>mysql -u user -h 192.168.1.2 -P 3306 -ppassword
```

or this:

```
>mysql -u user -h 192.168.1.2 -ppassword
```

...because 3306 is a default port number.

[mysql Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html)