# Connect to MySQL Database on Local Network

Tags: mysql, remote-server

I actually thought I could do this until I tried. I installed MySQL server on one PC in the Local network IP Address (192.168.1.4) and now I am trying to access it from another PC in the same network (192.168.1.5) but I am unable:

```
C:\Users\DOMICO>mysql -u domico -h 192.168.1.4 -p
Enter password: **********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'domico'@'DOMICO-PC' (using password:
 YES)
```

Surprisingly DOMICO-PC is the PC I am trying to connect from. Why is it not connecting to the given host but trying to connect to Local machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [connecting to mysql server on another PC in LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257455/connecting-to-mysql-server-on-another-pc-in-lan)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to give permissions to connect from remotehost

mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: I am getting that error, ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.16' (111)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have proper permissions to connect. In the computer that has the DB installed, give your user the proper permissions:

```
mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'domico'@'DOMICO-PC';
mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You can read more here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

And here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html

Answer (score 0):

This is connecting to the intended host as you require it to. t is just stating who is connecting. and where from.

USER@DOMAIN

user : your user running the mysql command
domain : name of the system you are connecting from.

Log into mysql via the server using -u root, ensure the user 'domico' is created and has sufficient access.

Comment: When creating the user I granted all on domico.* to the user 'domico' what other access do they require?

Comment: show me the grants you have set up for 'domico' in the DB. are you positive you are entering in the correct password as well?

Comment: The point is, you probably gave ALL privileges on the @localhost (which means you can only access the database from the local computer). You need to specify the proper host (computer) - @'DOMICO-PC', when giving privileges, as I wrote in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

creata a new user by mysql server 
and give it privileges you can do it by command and by using any server e.g by using workbench

Comment: Is this neccessary on a two year old question that already has an accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

**For all users  and all host.**

```
mysql -u root -p

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON *.*
TO '%'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

QUIT;
```