# Connecting to MySql server from different PC in LAN

Tags: mysql, minecraft, bungeecord

I have a XAMP server configured in a pc where I am running Minecraft servers. I also have a MySQL database that is needed by one of the Minecraft server plugins.

I can access PhpMyAdmin and modify things from the other PCs in my network without problems, but, when my plugin in the other computer tries to run it says that I have no  privileges for `USERIMUSING@THEOTHERCOMPUTER`. In PhpMyAdmin I already gave the users `ALL PRIVILEGES` in `%` hosts.

I think the problem is in my SQL, or, I'm not giving the permissions the way I should.

The error is basically I CAN'T ACCESS THIS DATABASE with THIS USER from THIS COMPUTER.

Comment: Probably this question is already answered here by @Tom: [connect-to-mysql-database-on-local-network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190116/connect-to-mysql-database-on-local-network). All you need is: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION; And then remember to FLUSH PRIVILEGES. And make sure your firewall isn't blocking the connection.

Comment: Also, try this: [how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Comment: As i said before, i already granted all the privileges that way and to the bind-addres thing ... the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to configure the listening address. By default the mysql-server only listens on the local computer. To change that, see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/5781420