# Connection to a Local Database

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio

I'm working on a Text-based RPG game using C++ in Visual Studio, where I want player account details and infomation to sit on a database, and I have previously been using Microsoft Azure to host a database. However there are a few pricing complications involved and since this is a small project and I'm learning on the way, I'm not sure about this.

I have 2 machines, my main PC and a Laptop, and I sometimes do some SQL practice on my laptop using MySQL Workbench, then I'll code on my main PC. Both of these machine use the same network, and so I want to ask:

If I set up a local database using MySQL Workbench on my laptop, will I be able to connect to it from my main PC? If so this will relieve a load of stress as I can then develop everything locally and then look to push it out to a larger scale in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to connect to the MySQL instance on your laptop from your PC, but you might have to open up the port to new connections.

There are other posts on SO that might be helpful with the specific steps needed: [Connect to MySQL Database on Local Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190116/connect-to-mysql-database-on-local-network)

Might be easiest to just run the same version of MySQL Workbench on both machines.

Comment: Thank you @mgrollins, this should be fine then, I can start working on a local connection for this! Yes I know it'll be more simple to run MySQL Workbench on both machines, I just want to get used to connecting to a DB on a different PC altogether if that makes sense. Thank you for this answer!

Comment: Sure thing! Good luck!