# Accessing database over LAN

Tags: android, mysql, wampserver

I am running a wampserver on my PC with a MySQL database which contains few tables. I have an android phone connected to the LAN. Will I be able to access the database with an android app running on the phone? Is the sever only limited to my PC or it is available on the entire local network?

Comment: it should be accessable one way or another over the entire network. I've not tried accessing mysql directly. Indirectly i can access Mysql via phpmyadmin and also via sites which connect via php. One issue is that if you create a server name on apache, such as www.mysite.com, then you wouldn't be able to access it via the servername unless you could alter the hosts file which I believe requires the android device to be rooted. You'd have to access it by the ip address (may be other alternatives to this, eg go via an external site such as wave.webaim if you have a domain name setup).

Comment: Checkout [connecting to mysql server on another PC in LAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257455/connecting-to-mysql-server-on-another-pc-in-lan). This may be of help.