# Access local MySQL server within my network

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that has a page that needs to show all the information that is in the local MySQL server (not in the hosting). How am I gonna do that?

I only tried to change the connection details but no luck on that matter.

db_connect.php (connect to hosting server)

```
<?php 
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "xxx";
   $password = "yyy";
   $database = "dbdb";

   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

   if($conn->connect_error){
        die("FAILED TO CONNECT : " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
?>
```

to db_local.php (connect to my local server)

```
<?php 
   $servername = "192.168.x.xx";
   $username = "";
   $password = "";
   $database = "info";

   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

   if($conn->connect_error){
       die("FAILED TO CONNECT : " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
?>
```

Is it possible? I only need to do that as a first aid solution in my main problem. I am getting this kind of error:

> FAILED TO CONNECT : Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.x.xx' (110)

Comment: is the port opened?
this might be helpful as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user ?

Comment: It won't work unless your local computer is exposed to the internet and has a static ip address.

Comment: Try to modifiy your Hosts File

Answer (score 0):

mysql might only accept connections from localhost, if you are connecting to the db from your local computer then you need to change the address to `localhost`

If you are not connecting to the DB via local machine then you need to make sure that port 3306 is open on the server, selinux is off ( assuming you are on linux ) and that you have the proper credentials.

If that doesnt work edit your `my.cnf` and change the line `bind-address: 127.0.0.1` to the machines local ip.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works...

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html
[connecting to mysql server on another PC in LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257455/connecting-to-mysql-server-on-another-pc-in-lan)