# How to fix "connection failed mysql odbc 8.0(a) driver bad handshake" Error in MySQL Connector/ODBC

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

[image]

connection failed mysql odbc 8.0(a) driver bad handshake

Comment: if the server is not runing in localhost, you need some configuration like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257455/connecting-to-mysql-server-on-another-pc-in-lan

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there are 2 ways to solve it **:**

1. Your MySQL version should be upper than v5.5
2. Use MySQL ODBC version 5.3.9

I hope you encountered same problems with me.

Comment: I quite agree.... Big like man