# MySQL problem with Host Mask and users grants

Tags: mysql, mask, host

I have install MySQLWorkbench 8.
I have 4 Users :

[image: 4 Users root:local, root:% dad:% Elefteria:%]

In Query is ask this:

[image: Show Grants for this Users]

But only for root:localhost i received the grants.

[image: This is the report]

if I change to root@% the result are ok.
if I change to dad@% the result are ok. etc.

if I tried : root@127.0.0.1 or root@192.168.1.11 or anything similar ==> error...

I can't connect from LAN to database.

I have restart MSQLServer8.0 ... nothing.
I have reinstall MSQLServer and Workbench... nothing...

Can u assist me please ?

Comment: the ip after the tells the ysql serve rfrom which ip the user can acces the server. Which means that dad is not connecting from something .11, and so on

Comment: all the connections I tried from 192.168.1.11... the same computer... i tried and as 127.0.0.1 and nothing... only if i set dad@% works and takes grants

Comment: for example: if i wrote SHOW GRANTS for dad@'%'; the grants are showing. If I wrote dad@127.0.0.1 or dad@192.168.1.11 or dad@localhost it gives me the error

Comment: if I Add a user dad with Mask localhost I receive the grands ok. but not if I wrote dad@127.0.0.1 or dad@192.168.1.11 and in Host Mask the dad is '%'.. that means dad can connect from any address.

Comment: you need also to check the firewall, if the computer allows access from the lan, onöy changig the @ipadress doesn't help alone.

Comment: I tried with firewall off, I saw that the port 3306 and the mysql is on exceptions.. but the problem exists...

Comment: try to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257455/connecting-to-mysql-server-on-another-pc-in-lan or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Comment: Sorry... My mistake... I can connect to database from LAN and other... I Cant take the user's Grants ... I can only take the root@localhost... if I check for the others users I received the errors.

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS` doesn't process the wildcards. When you say `for root@192.168.1.11` it looks for a grant specifically for that IP, it won't look for the wildcard `root@%`.

Comment: Ohh.. I didn't know that I could only write the user's name to get the grants. I thought I should also write the @…. Now I am taking the grants... I wrote only SHOW GRANT for dad ... and I received the grants. Thx all