# Cant connect to mysql using buildozer and kivy

Tags: mysql, kivy, buildozer

Using pymysql returns error in **Error log**. mysql-connector gives similar error.
Removing sql from code eliminates the problem and app works fine.
Tried with and witouth port in sql connection, firewall is disabled sqlclient on phone works.

## mysql connection:

```
mysql = pymysql.connect(
    host = "192.168.1.10",
    port = 3306,
    user = "user",
    passwd = "pass",
    database = "testdatabase"
```

## error log:

```
3-08 14:37:53.672 32696 32750 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
03-08 14:37:53.672 32696 32750 I python  :    File "/home/.../.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a_arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/KlimaApp/arm64-v8a/pymysql/connections>
03-08 14:37:53.672 32696 32750 I python  :    File "/home/..../.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a_arm64-v8a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/>
03-08 14:37:53.672 32696 32750 I python  :    File "/home/......./.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a_arm64-v8a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/>
03-08 14:37:53.672 32696 32750 I python  :    File "/home/....p/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a_arm64-v8a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/>
03-08 14:37:53.672 32696 32750 I python  :  PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
03-08 14:37:53.672 32696 32750 I python  :
03-08 14:37:53.672 32696 32750 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
03-08 14:37:53.673 32696 32750 I python  :
03-08 14:37:53.673 32696 32750 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
03-08 14:37:53.673 32696 32750 I python  :    File "/home/mads/Documents/Kivy/klimaapp/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 35, in <module>
03-08 14:37:53.673 32696 32750 I python  :    File "/home/mads/Documents/Kivy/klimaapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a_arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/KlimaApp/arm64-v8a/pymysql/connections>
03-08 14:37:53.673 32696 32750 I python  :    File "/home/mads/Documents/Kivy/klimaapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a_arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/KlimaApp/arm64-v8a/pymysql/connections>
03-08 14:37:53.673 32696 32750 I python  :  pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.67' ([Errno 1] Operation not permitted)")
03-08 14:37:53.673 32696 32750 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

## buildozer.spec:

`

```
requirements = python3,kivy,pymysql

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0
android.permission = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 34


android.archs = armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = master


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1
```

Comment: if the mysql server is on another computer, you need to configure it properly see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257455/connecting-to-mysql-server-on-another-pc-in-lan

Comment: mysql server is already configured with privileges to grant access to external computers. Works from other PCs and cellphones.

Comment: then check the prvileges of the user that tries to connect, also check the mysql error log

Comment: Error log is clean.