strapi db connection error with mysql remote db
Error: Access denied for user 'pool18'@'192.168.105.3' (using password: YES)                          │
│   at Packet.asError                                                                                     │
│   (C:\Users\Somji\workspace\2024\skymet_strapi_new\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:738:17)    │
│   at ClientHandshake.execute                                                                            │
│   (C:\Users\Somji\workspace\2024\skymet_strapi_new\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)   │
│   at Connection.handlePacket                                                                            │
│   (C:\Users\Somji\workspace\2024\skymet_strapi_new\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:481:34)        │
│   at PacketParser.onPacket                                                                              │
│   (C:\Users\Somji\workspace\2024\skymet_strapi_new\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:97:12)         │
│   at PacketParser.executeStart                                                                          │
│   (C:\Users\Somji\workspace\2024\skymet_strapi_new\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)      │
│   at Socket.<anonymous>                                                                                 │
│   (C:\Users\Somji\workspace\2024\skymet_strapi_new\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:104:25)        │
│   at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)                                                                   │
│   at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)                                                                   │
│   at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)                                                   │
│   at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)  


for lan access you need to grant the user privileges and allow hin access from Lan see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257455/connecting-to-mysql-server-on-another-pc-in-lan and please read the all answers

This question is similar to: Connecting to MySQL server on another PC in LAN. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Did you configure your setting properly in config/databae.js file and set the env variable correctly.

Yes,I did it properly for both env and db config file.

This is not an answer. You may want to delete it and provide it as a comment in context of the related question and/or answer that it was intended to be a response to.

You have not granted access to the user.
Refer to how to grant user permissions: MySQL: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES) except root user

yes i have granted all permissions for my ip
